# Tinting repeated items in listBox

Tags: c#, colors, listbox, duplicates

Let's say I have a listBox filled with items, but some of them are duplicate. I DO NOT want, however, to simply delete them, instead I want to highlight them with a color.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
void btnAddSelectedItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ListItem> itemsToAdd= new List<ListItem>();

    foreach (ListItem listItem in lstbxFromUserProjects.Items)
    {
        if (listItem.Selected)
            itemsToAdd.Add(listItem);
    }

    foreach (ListItem listItem in itemsToAdd)
    {

        if (!lstBoxToUserProjects.Items.Contains(listItem)) 
        {
            lstBoxToUserProjects.Items.Add(listItem);
        }
    }
}
```

How could I improve this to add the items, but color them? All the same color, but all duplicates must be colored, everything else needs no coloring.

I'm sorry if I'm not being clear enough, I can explain it better if anyone feels the need to.

Thanks in advance, folks.

Comment: @P1CUnrelated Ok this is C#, the code syntax confirm that too. But still the question : what platform? My answer assumed this is WPF let us know if this isn't

Comment: Pardon me once again, my head is just not good lately. I'm using winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to achieve that this way :

First, add property in ListItem class to indicate whether an item is duplicate :

```
public class ListItem
{
    ....
    public bool IsDuplicate { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Second, in buttonAddSelectedItem click, mark duplicate item :

```
....
foreach (ListItem listItem in itemsToAdd)
{
    if (lstBoxToUserProjects.Items.Contains(listItem)) listItem.IsDuplicate = true;
    lstBoxToUserProjects.Items.Add(listItem);
}
....
```

Then you can set background color properly based on IsDuplcate property. For example using style trigger :

```
<ListBox>
    ....
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsDuplicate" Value="True" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    ....
</ListBox>
```